# MUI - What is newValue in the handleChange function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have this example code from MUI Tabs (https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tabs/#BasicTabs.tsx). The full code is below.

My question is, what is the `newValue` in this code? Which value is it reading and where did it come from? It throws an error without `event` so it seems like it's linked but I can't get a full understanding of this part.

```
  const handleChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent, newValue: number) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };
```

FULL CODE

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Tabs from '@mui/material/Tabs';
import Tab from '@mui/material/Tab';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

interface TabPanelProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  index: number;
  value: number;
}

function TabPanel(props: TabPanelProps) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && (
        <Box sx={{ p: 3 }}>
          <Typography>{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

function a11yProps(index: number) {
  return {
    id: `simple-tab-${index}`,
    'aria-controls': `simple-tabpanel-${index}`,
  };
}

export default function BasicTabs() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent, newValue: number) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: 'divider' }}>
        <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="basic tabs example">
          <Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
          <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
          <Tab label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} />
        </Tabs>
      </Box>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        Item One
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        Item Two
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
        Item Three
      </TabPanel>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the `newValue` its related to the tab index.

So when user changes a tab, the `MUI` code internally handles the `onChange` event call passing the event itself and the newValue (with the tab index clicked). And with it `MUI` identifies wich tab user have clicked and change it to take effect into screen.

You can check the definition [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-base/src/TabsUnstyled/useTabs.ts#L27).